# Why does the transition not work although I already add the transition line?

Tags: html, css

I try to create transition on Chrome so hovered element's height will add up, but I cant make this work.

I already tried to add the width on the element and the hovered element but it still won't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        div.konten {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        div.card {
            float: right;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: auto;
        }
        
        .konten {
            font-family: fontKL;
            color: #404040;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .konten h1 {
            font-size: 1.8vw;
        }
        
        .konten p {
            font-size: 1.3vw;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        
        .bawah {
            margin-right: 13%;
        }
        
        .cardb {
            width: 30.5%;
            max-height: 25px;
            transition: height 2s, transform 2s;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .cardb:hover {
            max-height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="konten">

            <div class="bawah">
                <div class="card cardb" style="background-color: rgba(94,123,85,0.8);">
                    <h1>Education</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card cardb" style="background-color: rgba(156,164,143,0.8);">
                    <h1>Experiences</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card cardb" style="background-color: rgba(123,138,86,0.8);">
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need the hovered element slides down smoothly with the transition but it won't slide smoothly with the transition line I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your transition to target max-height instead of height :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <style type="text/css">
 
  div.konten{
   width: 100%;
  }
  div.card{
   float: right;
   margin-bottom: 5%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   height: auto;
  }
  .konten{
   font-family: fontKL;
   color: #404040;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .konten h1{
   font-size: 1.8vw;
  }
  .konten p{
   font-size: 1.3vw;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .bawah{
   margin-right: 13%;
  }
  .cardb{
   width: 30.5%;
   max-height: 25px;
   transition: max-height 2s, transform 2s;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .cardb:hover{
   max-height: 250px;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="konten">


<div class="bawah">
<div class="card cardb" style="background-color: rgba(94,123,85,0.8);">
 <h1>Education</h1>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 </p>
</div>
<div class="card cardb" style="background-color: rgba(156,164,143,0.8);">
 <h1>Experiences</h1>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 </p>
</div>
<div class="card cardb" style="background-color: rgba(123,138,86,0.8);">
 <h1>Contact</h1>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```